# Misconception in implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

(a) Let $(x_0, y_0)$, where $y \neq 0$ be a point on the hyperbola $\frac{x^2} {a^2} - \frac{y^2} {b^2} = 1$. Find an equation of the tangent line to the hyperbola passing through $(x_0, y_0)$.

I thought this was a typical implicit differentiation problem, but I could not get the suggested answer.

**My working**

$$\frac {2x} {a^2} - \frac {dy} {dx} \frac {2y} {b^2} = 0$$

$$\implies \frac {dy} {dx} = \frac {b^2x} {a^2y}$$

Equation of tangent is $y = \frac {b^2x_0} {a^2y_0} (x - x_0) + y_0$.

**Suggested answer**

Equation of tangent is $\frac{x_0x} {a^2} - \frac {y_0y} {b^2} = 1$.

---

(b) Let $(x_0, y_0)$, where $y \neq 0$ be a point on the parabola $y^2 = 2px$. Find an equation of the tangent line to the parabola passing through $(x_0, y_0)$.

Similarly, I thought this was a typical implicit differentiation problem, but I also could not get the suggested answer.

**My working**

$$2y\frac {dy} {dx} = 2p$$

$$\implies \frac {dy} {dx} = \frac p y$$

Equation of tangent is $y = \frac {p} {y_0} (x - x_0) + y_0$.

**Suggested answer**

Equation of tangent is $y_0y = p(x + x_0)$.

---

The suggested answers are correct, so I must have done something wrong for both parts, though I know not what. Moreover, I have a hunch that it is the same mistake that I have repeated. Anyone kind enough to point out where I have gone wrong will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your first answer is correct, just multiply by $\frac{y_0}{b^2}$ and use the fact $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the hyperbola.

Comment: The second one is right as well, same argument.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Haha yes I see it now. My apologies. I did this really late at night after a long day's worth of work that included a calculus test in the morning as well :-)

Comment: Good luck. There's stuff in the old-fashioned books about conics about this trick of replacing the $x^2$ by $x x_0$ and so on, and the $x$s by $\frac{x+x_0}{2}$ ... I think it's called "polarising" the equation.

Comment: @ancientmathematician oh? I’ll definitely check it out. Thank you!!

Comment: It can be helpful for many such problems to put the equation for the tangent line into "general form": $$ y \ - \ y_0 \ \ = \ \ \frac{dy}{dx}|_{x_0} · ( x \ - \ x_0) \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \left(-\frac{dy}{dx} |_{x_0} \right) ·   x \ + \ y \ \ = \ \ \left(-\frac{dy}{dx} |_{x_0} \right) ·   x_0 \ + \ y_0 \ \ . $$  The remaining manipulations required are often easier starting from here.